# How do i calculate 1 byte checksum for a byte array

Tags: java, routes, protocols, checksum

I want to calculate 1 byte checksum for my network assignment of implementing routing protocol
as i am completely new please help me by providing me a source code of 1 byte checksum

Here is my simPhy.java class.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

/**
 * the IpAddress class handles ip address including functionalities such as whether two ip addresses are in the same network
 */
class IpAddress{
    /**
     * contains the ip address in byte format
     */
    byte[] ipAddr=new byte[4];

    /**
     * receives an ip address in string format and stores it in instance variable ipAddr
     *
     * @param ipString ip address in String format
     */
    public IpAddress(String ipString){                  
        StringTokenizer strTok=new StringTokenizer(ipString,".",false);     
        int i=0;
        String octet;
        while(strTok.hasMoreTokens()){
            octet=strTok.nextToken();
            ipAddr[i++]=(byte)Integer.valueOf(octet,10).intValue();
        }
    }

    /**
     * receives an ip address in array of bytes format and stores in instance variable ipAddr
     *
     * @param ip ip address in the array of bytes formats
     */
    public IpAddress(byte[] ip){
        System.arraycopy(ip, 0, ipAddr, 0, 4);
    }

    /**
     * returns ip address in array of bytes format
     *
     * @return ip address in array of bytes format
     */
    public byte[] getBytes(){return ipAddr;}

    /**
     * return ip address in String format
     *
     * @return ip address in String format
     */
    public String getString(){return new String((int)(ipAddr[0]& 0xFF)+"."+(int)(ipAddr[1]& 0xFF)+"."+(int)(ipAddr[2]& 0xFF)+"."+(int)(ipAddr[3]& 0xFF));}

    /**
     * calculates the network address of the ip address from supplied subnet mask
     *
     * @param mask subnet mask
     * @return IpAddress class having ip address set to the network address
     */
    public IpAddress getNetworkAddress(int mask){       
        byte[] netMask=new byte[4];
        //find mask
        int j=0;
        int tMask=128;
        for(int i=0;i<32;i++){          
            if(i<mask){
                tMask=(tMask>>1)|128;
            }
            if((i+1)%8==0){             
                netMask[j++]=(byte)tMask;
                tMask=0;
            }           
        }       
        //find network address      
        byte[] netAddr=new byte[4];
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){                       
            netAddr[i]=(byte)(ipAddr[i] & netMask[i]);
        }
        return new IpAddress(netAddr);
    }

    /**
     * checks whether the supplied instance of IpAddress has ip address which is in the the same network as that of the invoking instance
     *
     * @param ip instance of IpAddress
     * @param mask subnet mask
     * @return true if the supplied instance of IpAddress has ip address which is in the the same network as that of the invoking instance and false otherwise
     */
    public boolean sameSubnet(IpAddress ip, int mask){
        IpAddress network1=getNetworkAddress(mask);
        IpAddress network2=ip.getNetworkAddress(mask);
        return network1.sameIp(network2);
    }

    /**
     * checks whether the supplied instance of IpAddress has the same ip address as that of the invoking instance
     *
     * @param ip instance of IpAddress class
     * @return true if the supplied instance of IpAddress has the same ip address as that of the invoking instance and false otherwise
     */
    public boolean sameIp(IpAddress ip){        
        byte[] other=ip.getBytes();
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            if(ipAddr[i]!=other[i]){
                return false;               
            }   
        }
        return true;
    }   
}


/**
 * the Packet class defines the structure of packets in network layer
 */
class Packet{
    /**
     * ip address of the source encapsulated in an instance if IpAddress
     */
    IpAddress src;

    /**
     * ip address of the destination encapsulated in an instance if IpAddress
     */
    IpAddress dst;

    /**
     * actual data of the packet in array of bytes format
     */
    byte payload[];

    /**
     * initializes instance variables corresponding to source ip, destination ip, and payload
     *
     * @param an array of bytes containing source ip in first four slots, destination ip in second four slots, and the payload in rest 
     */
    Packet(byte[] a){
        byte[] srcIp=new byte[4];
        byte[] dstIp=new byte[4];
        payload=new byte[a.length-8];
        System.arraycopy(a, 0, srcIp, 0, 4);        
        System.arraycopy(a, 4, dstIp, 0, 4);        
        System.arraycopy(a, 8, payload, 0, a.length-8);     
        src=new IpAddress(srcIp);
        dst=new IpAddress(dstIp);
    }

    /**
     * initializes instance variables corresponding to source ip, destination ip, and payload
     * 
     * @param s source ip address encapsulated in an instance of IpAddress
     * @param d destination ip address encapsulated in an instance of IpAddress
     * @param a array of bytes containing the payload
     */
    Packet(IpAddress s, IpAddress d, byte[] a){     
        payload=new byte[a.length];     
        System.arraycopy(a, 0, payload, 0, a.length);       
        src=s;
        dst=d;
    }

    /**
     * returns the ip address of the source encapsulated in an instance of IpAddress
     *
     * @return ip address of the source encapsulated in an instance of IpAddress
     */
    IpAddress getSrcIp(){return src;}

    /**
     * returns the ip address of the destination encapsulated in an instance of IpAddress
     *
     * @return ip address of the destination encapsulated in an instance of IpAddress
     */
    IpAddress getDstIp(){return dst;}

    /**
     * returns the payload as array of bytes
     *
     * @return payload as array of bytes
     */
    byte[] getPayload(){return payload;}

    /**
     * returns an array of bytes with embedded source ip address in first four slots, destination ip address in second four slots, and the rest containing payload
     *
     * @return array of bytes having source ip in first four slots, destination ip in second four slots and payload in the rest
     */
    byte [] getBytes(){
        byte[] packet=new byte[payload.length+8];       
        try{
            System.arraycopy(src.getBytes(), 0, packet, 0, 4);      
            System.arraycopy(dst.getBytes(), 0, packet, 4, 4);      
            System.arraycopy(payload, 0, packet, 8, payload.length);        
            return packet;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * returns a string informing source ip address, destination ip address and payload
     *
     * @return string informing source ip address, destination ip address and payload
     */
    String getString(){             
        return new String("SrcIP="+src.getString()+ " | DestIP="+dst.getString()+" | Payload="+new String(payload));                        
    }   
}


/**
 * the Frame class defines the structure of frames in data link layer
 */
class Frame{
    /**
     * byte representing the source mac address 
     */
    byte srcMac;

    /**
     * byte representing the destination mac address
     */
    byte dstMac;    

    /**
     * array of bytes representing the payload
     */
    byte payload[];

    /**
     * checksum byte for error checking
     */
    byte checksum;

    /**
     * initializes instance variables corresponding to source mac address, destination mac address and payload
     *
     * @param a array of bytes containing source and destination mac address in first two slots respectively and payload in the rest
     */
    Frame(byte[] a){
        srcMac=a[0];
        dstMac=a[1];        
        payload=new byte[a.length-3];       
        try{
            System.arraycopy(a, 2, payload, 0, payload.length);
            checksum=a[a.length-1];
        }       
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * initializes instance variables corresponding to source mac address, destination mac address and payload
     *
     * @param s source mac address in integer format
     * @param d destination mac address in integer format
     * @param a payload in array of bytes
     */
    Frame(int s, int d, byte[] a){
        srcMac=(byte)s;
        dstMac=(byte)d;             
        payload=new byte[a.length];     
        try{
            System.arraycopy(a, 0, payload, 0, a.length);
            checksum=calculateChecksum(); 
        }       
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * initializes instance variables corresponding to source mac address, destination mac address, payload initialized to zero
     *
     * @param s source mac address in integer format
     * @param d destination mac address in integer format
     */
    Frame(int s, int d){        
        srcMac=(byte)s;
        dstMac=(byte)d;     
        payload=new byte[0];
        checksum=calculateChecksum();   
    }

    /**
     * returns source mac address in byte
     *
     * @return source mac address in byte
     */
    byte getSrcMac(){
        return srcMac;
    }

    /**
     * returns destination mac address in byte
     *
     * @return destination mac address in byte
     */
    byte getDstMac(){
        return dstMac;
    }   
    /**
     * returns value in the checksum field
     *
     * @return value in the checksum field
     */
    byte getChecksum(){     
        return checksum;
    }
    /**
     * returns payload in array of bytes
     *
     * @return payload in array of bytes
     */
    byte [] getPayload(){       
        return payload;
    }
    /**
     * returns an array of bytes with embedded mac address in first slot, destination mac address in second slot, and payload in the rest
     *
     * @return array of bytes having source mac address in first slot, destination mac address in second slot, and payload in the rest
     */
    byte [] getBytes(){
        byte[] frame=new byte[payload.length+3];
        frame[0]=srcMac;
        frame[1]=dstMac;        
        try{
            System.arraycopy(payload, 0, frame, 2, payload.length);
            frame[payload.length+2]=checksum;
            return frame;
        }       
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }       
    /**
     * Calculate one byte checksum for the frame
     *
     * @return checksum value
     */
    byte calculateChecksum(){
        /*Replace the following code with checksum generation algorithm to calculate checksum on src MAC, dst MAC and payload*/
        return 1;
    }
    /**
     * checks whether the frame has any checksum error
     *
     * @return true if checksum error is detected and false otherwise
     */
    boolean hasCheckSumError(){
        /*replace the following code with checksum verification*/
        return false;
    }   
    /**
     * returns a string informing source mac address, destination mac address and payload
     *
     * @return string informing source mac address, destination mac address and payload
     */
    String getString(){                     
        return new String("Src Mac="+(int)(srcMac& 0xFF)+ " | Dst Mac="+(int)(dstMac& 0xFF));                       
    }       
}


/**
 * class ByteArray is a custom method to manipulate array of bytes
 */
class ByteArray{
    /**
     * array of bytes to be manipulated
     */
    byte[] bArray;

    /**
     * instantiates instance variable corresponding to array of bytes
     *
     * @param size size of the array
     */
    ByteArray(int size){
        bArray=new byte[size];
    }

    /**
     * initializes instance variable with the supplied array of bytes
     *
     * @param b array of bytes
     */
    ByteArray(byte[] b){
        bArray=new byte[b.length];
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, bArray, 0, b.length);
    }

    /**
     * stores value of supplied array of bytes b in instance variable bArray, starting from an specified index of bArray
     * 
     * @param index index of instance variable bArray from where the copy should start
     * @param b array of bytes to be stored in instance variable bArray 
     */
    void setAt(int index, byte[] b){
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, bArray, index, b.length);
    }

    /**
     * returns byte value at specified index of instance variable bArray
     * 
     * @param index index of instance variable bArray from which byte value should be retrieved
     * @return byte value at specified index of instance variable bArray
     */
    byte getByteVal(int index){return bArray[index];}

    /**
     * stores byte value at specified index of instance variable bArray
     * 
     * @param index index of instance variable bArray to which byte value should be stored
     */
    void setByteVal(int index, byte b){bArray[index]=b;}

    /**
     * returns a portion of instance variable bArray according to supplied index from which copy should start, along with number of bytes to be copied 
     * 
     * @param index index of bArray from which copy should start
     * @param length number of bytes to be copied
     * @return array of bytes containing portion of instance variable bArray as specified through parameters 
     */
    byte[] getAt(int index, int length){
        byte[] temp=new byte[length];
        System.arraycopy(bArray, index, temp, 0, length);
        return temp;
    }

    /**
     * returns array of bytes containing value of instance variable bArray
     *
     * @return array of bytes containing value of instance variable bArray
     */
    byte[] getBytes(){return bArray;}

    /**
     * returns size of instance variable bArray
     *
     * @return size of instance variable bArray
     */
    int getSize(){return bArray.length;}
}


/**
 * class Buffer<T> acts as a generic storage class
 */
class Buffer<T>{
    /**
     * array of supplied type
     */
    T data[];

    /**
     * size of the buffer
     */
    int size;

    /**
     * index of the start of the buffer
     */
    int head;

    /**
     * index of the end of the buffer
     */
    int tail;

    /**
     * name of the buffer
     */
    String name;

    /**
     * initializes name and size of buffer
     *
     * @param n String denoting name of the buffer
     * @param sz integer denoting size of the buffer
     */
    Buffer(String n, int sz){
        name=n;
        size=sz+1;
        data=(T[])new Object[size]; 
        head=0;
        tail=0;
    }

    /**
     * checks whether buffer is empty
     *
     * @return true if buffer is empty and false otherwise
     */
    synchronized boolean empty(){
        if (head==tail) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    /**
     * checks whether buffer is full
     *
     * @return true if buffer is full and false otherwise
     */
    synchronized boolean full(){
        if((tail+1)%size==head) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    /**
     * stores a single item in buffer if space is available and dropped otherwise
     *
     * @param t element of type T that should be stored
     * @return true of storage was successful and false otherwise
     */
    synchronized boolean store(T t){
        if(full()){
            System.out.println(name+" Buffer Full. Dropping Packet ...");
            return false;
        }
        else{
            tail=(tail+1)%size;
            data[tail]=t;                       
            return true;
        }       
    }

    /**
     * returns a single item from head of the buffer if buffer is not empty and null otherwise
     *
     * @return a single item from head of the buffer if buffer is not empty and null otherwise
     */
    synchronized T get(){
        if(empty()){
            System.out.println(name+" Buffer Empty.");
            return null;
        }
        else {
        head=(head+1)%size;
        return data[head];      
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple ways to do it. See an [example](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/ip-header-checksum) here on how checksum is calculated. You simply add up all the data in the byte array, carry forward the bits and do a 1's complement.

Comment: no checksum algorithm was given - so there can be no certain answer ^^ you gave the best answer possible!